# Is there a grammatically accurate chart for reported speech in German?

Tags: grammar

If there is one, it would be immensely helpful for anyone wanting to see clearly how the verbs change in reported speech. I still don't know (very well) how to make all the necessary changes from direct to indirect speech.

Comment: What do you find lacking in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirekte_Rede ?

Comment: Another link: http://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/indirekte-rede

Comment: Third link, ready to use as template for a great answer http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Here are links for details on reported speech and charts for verb conjugation as per comments:

- [Wikipedia: Indirekte Rede](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirekte_Rede)
- [Lingolia: Indirekte Rede](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/indirekte-rede)
- [Canoo: Reported Speech](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html?lang=en)